# A Log sine integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms

How to prove that 
$$\int_{\rm{0}}^{\frac{\pi }{{\rm{2}}}} {{t^4}} {\left( {\ln 2\sin t} \right)^2}dt = \frac{{{\pi ^3}}}{8}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{H_n}{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}}}}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^3}}}}  - \frac{{3\pi }}{4}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{H_n}{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}}}}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^5}}}}  + \frac{{{\pi ^7}}}{{{2^7} \cdot 105}}\ ?$$
where $H_n$ denotes the classical harmonic number defined by
$$H_n:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}.$$

In general, the log sine integrals
$$\int_{\rm{0}}^{\frac{\pi }{{\rm{2}}}} {{t^p}} {\left( {\ln 2\sin t} \right)^q}dt = ?$$
it can be expressed in terms of multiple zeta values?

Comment: But also, *why* to prove, perhaps? Is this someone's well-known formula?

Comment: I feel that the above integrals can be expressed as multiple zeta values or Euler sums.

Comment: The LHS is about $0.7807$ while the RHS is about $0.5027$ so you may have made a typo somewhere.